# Finding a formula for the sequence $\{1, 7, 17, 30, 48, 70, 95, 125, \ldots\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, number-theory, recurrence-relations, pattern-recognition

I have a sequence
$$f = \{1, 7, 17, 30, 48, 70, 95, 125, \ldots\}$$

The difference between the entries of f is
$$\triangledown f = \{6, 10, 13, 18, 22, 25, 30, \ldots\}$$

Finally, the difference between the entries of $\triangledown f$ is
$$\{4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 3, \ldots\}$$
repeating.

I've been trying to find an equation for $f$, but am struggling to piece it together.

Hints would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If $n=1$ maps to the first entry of the $f$ sequence. The equation is just $2n^2-\lceil\frac{n}{3}\rceil$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can decompose your problem into 2 simpler ones, and then add solutions.

Second difference, which I will denote by $\Delta^2 f$ is sum of 2 sequences:
$$
(4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 5, \ldots) = (4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, \ldots) + (0, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1, \ldots)
$$
Let $\Delta^2 g = (4, 4, \ldots)$ and $\Delta^2 h = (0, -1, 1, \ldots)$ be such that $f = g + h$. Now solving for general g is easy, we have
\begin{align}
\Delta g(n) &= 4n + \Delta g(0), \\
g(n) &= 2n(n-1) + n\Delta g(0) + g(0).
\end{align} Second one is a bit less standard, but due to being sort of 'balanced', we can easily guess particular solution
$$
\begin{array}
.\Delta^2 h &&&& 0&& -1&& 1&& 0&& -1&& 1&& 0&& -1&& 1&\ldots\\
  \Delta h &&& 0&& 0&& -1&& 0&& 0&& -1&& 0&& 0&& -1&\ldots\\
         h && 0&& 0&& 0&& -1&& -1&& -1&& -2&& -2&& -2&\ldots\\
\end{array}
$$
So we see that possible $h$ would be $(0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -2, -2, -2, -3, -3, -3, -4, \ldots)$.
We have $\Delta f(0) = \Delta g(0) + \Delta h(0) = \Delta g(0)$ and $f(0) = g(0) + h(0) = g(0)$. This gives initial conditions for $g$, and we arrive on
$$f(n) = 2n(n-1) + 6n + 1 -\left\lfloor \frac n 3\right\rfloor.$$

Comment: you can simplify the final equation by shifting the index by 1. If $n=0$ maps to the first entry of the $f$ sequence then we would have your equation mentioned at the bottom of your answer. If $n=1$ maps to the first entry instead the final equation is just $2n^2-\lceil\frac{n}{3}\rceil$

Answer (score 1):

Using $1$-based indices, for any integer $n \ge 1$, the entries in $f$ of $f_n$, $f_{n+1}$ and $f_{n+2}$ have first order differences of $f_{n+1}-f_{n}$ and $f_{n+2}-f_{n+1}$, so their second order difference would be

$$(f_{n+2}-f_{n+1}) - (f_{n+1}-f_{n}) = f_{n+2} - 2f_{n+1} + f_{n} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Thus, if $n = 3k+1$ for some integer $k \ge 0$, from your repeating second order differences, we get

$$f_{n+2} - 2f_{n+1} + f_{n} = 4 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

$$f_{n+3} - 2f_{n+2} + f_{n+1} = 3 \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

$$f_{n+4} - 2f_{n+3} + f_{n+2} = 5 \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Adding \eqref{eq2A}, \eqref{eq3A} and \eqref{eq4A} gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
f_{n+4} - f_{n+3} - f_{n+1} + f_{n} & = 12 \\
f_{n+4} & = f_{n+3} + f_{n+1} - f_{n} + 12
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

If $n = 3k+2$ instead, then the RHS of \eqref{eq2A} would $3$, that of \eqref{eq3A} would $5$, and in \eqref{eq4A} would be $4$. Nonetheless, the sum of the RHS would still be $12$, so \eqref{eq5A} is still true. The same thing happens for the $n = 3k + 3$ case. Thus, \eqref{eq5A} applies for all $n \ge 1$.

Note that \eqref{eq5A} is a [linear recurrence relation with constant coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_recurrence_with_constant_coefficients). Since the $b$ value is $12$ here, it's classified as being nonhomogeneous. The [conversion to homogeneous form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_recurrence_with_constant_coefficients#Conversion_to_homogeneous_form) section explains the conversion process. In particular, we can first try to use

$$y^{*} = \frac{b}{1-a_{1}-\cdots -a_{n}}$$

where the $a_i$ are the coefficients, as long as the denominator is not $0$. Unfortunately, here $a_1 = 1$, $a_2 = 1$, $a_3 = 0$ and $a_4 = -1$ causes the denominator to be $0$. Thus, we need to use its alternate suggestion, in particular applying \eqref{eq5A} with $n$ replaced by $n + 1$ to get

$$f_{n+5} = f_{n+4} + f_{n+2} - f_{n+1} + 12 \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

Subtracting \eqref{eq5A} from this results in

$$f_{n+5}= 2f_{n+4} - f_{n+3} + f_{n+2} - 2f_{n+1} + f_{n} \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

This is now in homogenous form, so we can solve this using the [general solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_recurrence_with_constant_coefficients#General_solution) method. In particular, we first need to find the roots of the characteristic polynomial, with this being

$$\lambda^5 = 2\lambda^4 - \lambda^3 + \lambda^2 - 2\lambda + 1 \tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$

Fortunately, there's one fairly obvious root of $\lambda = 1$. Factoring this out, and then also several other factors, we get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
0 & = (\lambda - 1)(-\lambda^4 + \lambda^3 + \lambda - 1) \\
& = (\lambda - 1)(-\lambda^3(\lambda - 1) + (\lambda - 1)) \\
& = (\lambda - 1)^2(-1)(\lambda^3 - 1) \\
& = (-1)(\lambda - 1)^3(\lambda^2 + \lambda + 1)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{9}\label{eq9A}$$

The roots of $\lambda^2 + \lambda + 1$ are $\lambda = \frac{-1\pm\sqrt{3}i}{2}$, i.e., they're complex. The Wikipedia article explains how to finish determining the solution, which I'm leaving to anybody interested.